# Passing values from EntityFieldQuery to db_select

Tags: 7, database

Checked for this, but don't seem to be any specific answers to this question.

I'm trying to pass results from EntityFieldQuery to a db_select query, via a string. However, although debugging both queries with set values shows that they are operating correctly and providing the desired results, when using the string in db_select I am getting null results.

The purpose is to get certain node ID's as an integer value and pass them as an array of Entity_ID integer values, so the db_select function only selects table rows which match a certain Entity_ID.

I presume I'm making a output format error for the EntityFieldQuery, but can't work out what exactly it is.  Code is as follows:

```
// EntityFieldQuery
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
                   ->entityCondition('bundle', 'contenttype1')
                   ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
                    ->fieldCondition('field_field', 'value', $contenttype2, '=')
                   ->fieldOrderBy('field_field', 'value', 'ASC')
                    ->execute();

// Debugging functions only, return correct values when tested
$show = array_keys($entities['node']);
echo 'this is show: ' . $show;

$print = var_dump($show);
echo 'this is print: ' . $print;

// db_select function, returns correct sum when '$entities' is replaced with integer value for entity_id
$dbquery = db_select('tablename', 't')
  ->condition('t.entity_id', '$entities', '=');
$dbquery->addExpression('SUM(value)', 'value');

$result = $dbquery->execute()->fetchField();

// Debugging function only
print 'this is result: ' . $result;
```

The EntityFieldQuery is producing the correct values, but it isn't clear that they are in the correct format. The $print output is:

```
array(2) { [0]=>int(213) [1]=>int(214) }
```

At present, the SUM result works correctly when I replace '$entities' in the db_select with (e.g.) '213', but returns 0.0 when I use '$entities'.

EDIT: using

```
dpq($dbquery); 
dpr($result);
```

Gives the confirm message:

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS value
FROM 
{votingapi_vote} v
WHERE  (v.entity_id = )
```

And the error message:

```
Warning: PDO::quote() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in dpq() (line 1835 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/devel/devel.module).
```

What is the output format code / function I should be using for EntityFieldQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. after getting your entities using **EntityFieldQuery**, create a **for loop** in order to check the **val** that was stored in your **variable $entities**. Then use **dsm or dpm** to check if it **returns a result**.

```
$results = '';
for ($i=0; $i < count($your_entity) ; $i++) { 
    $query = db_select('yourtablename', 't');
    $query->fields('t');
    $query->condition('t.entity_id', $your_variable);
    $results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
}
dsm($results);
```

Hope this helps you.